# Static function "does not exist" on injected class

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I set up a class with a bunch of static utility functions.

```
// utils.ts
class Utils {
    public static blank(anything) {
        if (_.isNil(anything) || anything === "") {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

    // ...
}

window.Utils = Utils;
```

I inject this into my angular app as a constant:

```
angular.module("myApp", []).constant("Utils", window.Utils);
```

Then I can use it in my controllers or in a provider:

```
class MyCtrl {
    constructor(private $scope, private Utils: Utils, private MyService: MyService) { }

    // ...
}

angular.module("myApp").controller("MyCtrl", MyCtrl);
```

However, when I compile I get this error:

```
javascripts/admin/controllers/my_ctrl.ts(6,29): error TS2339:
Property 'blank' does not exist on type 'Utils'.
```

How can I get the correct type information on static methods when injecting a constant like this into an angular controller?

Comment: `private Utils: Utils`: so, you're telling TypeScript that Utils is an **instance** of the class Utils, although it is not. Why do you use static methods instead of instance methods. And why don't you define Utils as a service, rather than a constant?

Comment: It's supposed to work the same way a library like lodash works, which does not need to be instantiated. I'm defining it as a constant so that I can use it in providers. I wasn't able to do that with a service. Is there a way to tell the compiler I'm injecting a class, rather than an instance of it?

Answer (score 0):

The correct type of injected `private Utils` is not `Utils`, which would imply an instantiated instance of the class `Utils`.

The correct type is `typeof Utils`, which tells TypeScript that `private Utils` is the class itself *(or rather, something with the same type as the class Utils)*, not an instance of the class.

You will also need to use another name for the *type* Utils or the *parameter* Utils. The unary expression passed for TypeScripts `typeof` will include the parameters in its scope, so simply changing `:Utils` to `:typeof Utils` will cause error about circular reference.

Something like this should do the trick

```
constructor(private $scope, private Utils: typeof window.Utils, private MyService: MyService){ }
```

Comment: I tried `typeof window.Utils` and did not get any errors. But when I tried using a function that did not exist as a static function of `Utils`, it didn't give me an error. It should give me an error if I try to do `this.Utils.notReal()` as long as `public static notReal() { }` is not defined on my `Utils` class, right?

Comment: @Shaun Hmm, weird. I suppose the compiler doesn't have the full type info of `window.Utils` for some reason and thinks it's `any` or something... You could also try renaming the property instead, like `private utils: typeof Utils`. In your original example, did `this.Utils` work "correctly" for the instance methods? That is, did `this.Utils.notReal()` give errors and did `this.Utils.realInstanceMehtod()` work?

Comment: If I just leave it without a type, then it's just taken as `any` and doesn't throw errors on any methods I pass to it. I'm using it without instantiating any objects and it works correctly in the app, but I don't get any typing assistance or checks. But maybe that's the wrong way to approach it with Angular's dependency injection design.